# one shell command to find every n-gram works in text

Tags: shell, text-processing, grep, perl

I have a text stream or a file that contains words separated by whitespace. 
Like:

```
I have a toy. you may not like it.
```

Every whitespace-separated word may be composed by two or more small words, maybe organized by camel case (separated by different case), snake case (separated by underline) or separated by dot, like:

```
I_amAManTest you_haveAHouse FOO_BAR_test.model
```

for example:

```
I_amAManTest
```

can be split into:

```
I
am
A
Man
Test
```

but I want to print every *n* words (every subset of contiguous small words)
in the compound word, like:

```
I_amAManTest
```

output:

```
// from first word on
I
I_am
I_amA
I_amAMan
I_amAManTest
// from second word on 
am
amA
amAMan
amAManTest
// from third word on 
A
AMan
AManTest
// from fourth word on
Man
ManTest
// from fifth word on
Test
```

So in conclusion, for input like

```
I_amAManTest you_haveAHouse FOO_BAR_test
```

the output should be

```
I
I_am
I_amA
I_amAMan
I_amAManTest
am
amA
amAMan
amAManTest
A
AMan
AManTest
Man
ManTest
Test
you
you_have
you_haveA
you_haveAHouse
have
haveA
haveAHouse
A
AHouse
House
FOO
FOO_BAR
FOO_BAR_test
BAR
BAR_test
test
```

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail?

Comment: Since you already know how to split a sentence into space-separated words, why clutter your question and make it harder for us to read/understand by including that aspect in your question and example rather than just focusing your question/example on how to split one string with no spaces into "words" per your criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A (mostly-)`sed` solution:

```
cat "$@" |
    tr -cs -- '._[:alpha:]' '[\n*]' |
    sed -n  -e 'h; :ms' \
            -e 'p; :ss' \
                -e 's/\([[:lower:]]\)[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]*$/\1/p; t ss' \
                -e 's/\([[:lower:]]\)[[:upper:]][[:upper:]]*$/\1/p; t ss' \
                -e 's/\([[:upper:]]\)[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]\+$/\1/p; t ss' \
                -e 's/[._][[:alpha:]][[:lower:]]*$//p; t ss' \
                -e 's/[._][[:upper:]]\+$//p; t ss' \
            -e 'g' \
            -e 's/^[[:upper:]]\?[[:lower:]]\+\([[:upper:]]\)/\1/; t mw' \
            -e 's/^[[:upper:]]\+\([[:upper:]][[:lower:]]\)/\1/; t mw' \
            -e 's/^[[:alpha:]][[:lower:]]*[._]//; t mw' \
            -e 's/^[[:upper:]]\+[._]//; t mw' \
            -e 'b' \
            -e ':mw; h; b ms'
```

The algorithm is

```
for each compound word (e.g., “FOO_BAR_test”) in the input
do
    repeat
        print what you’ve got
        repeat
            remove a small word from the end (e.g., “FOO_BAR_test” → “FOO_BAR”) and print what’s left
        until you’re down to the last one (e.g., “FOO_BAR_test” → “FOO”)
        go back to what you had at the beginning of the above loop
          and remove a small word from the beginning
          (e.g., “FOO_BAR_test” → “BAR_test”) ... but don’t print anything
    until you’re down to the last one (e.g., “FOO_BAR_test” → “test”)
end for loop
```

Details:

- `cat "$@"` is a UUOC. 
  I usually avoid these;
  you can do `tr args < file`,
  but you can’t pass multiple files to `tr` directly.
- `tr -cs -- '._[:alpha:]' '[\n*]'` breaks a line of many compound words
  into separate lines; e.g.,

  ```
  I_amAManTest you_haveAHouse FOO_BAR_test
  ```

  becomes

  ```
  I_amAManTest
  you_haveAHouse
  FOO_BAR_test
  ```

  so sed can process one compound word at a time.
- `sed -n` — don’t print anything automatically; print only when commanded to.
- `-e` specifies that the following **e**xpression is part of the sed script.
- `h` — copy the pattern space to the hold space.
- `:ms` — a label (Main loop Start)
- `p` — print
- `:ss` — a label (Secondary loop Start)
- The following commands remove a small word from the end of a compound word,
  and, if successful,
  print the result and jump back to the beginning of the Secondary loop.

  - `s/\([[:lower:]]\)[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]*$/\1/p; t ss` — changes “nTest” to “n”.
  - `s/\([[:lower:]]\)[[:upper:]][[:upper:]]*$/\1/p; t ss` — changes “mOK” to “m”.
  - `s/\([[:upper:]]\)[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]\+$/\1/p; t ss` — changes “AMan” to “A”.
  - `s/[._][[:alpha:]][[:lower:]]*$//p; t ss` — deletes “_am”
    (replaces it with nothing).
  - `s/[._][[:upper:]]\+$//p; t ss` — deletes “_BAR” (replaces it with nothing).
- This is the end of the Secondary loop.
- `g` — copy the hold space to the pattern space
  (go back to what you had at the beginning of the above loop).
- The following commands remove a small word
  from the beginning of a compound word, and, if successful,
  jump down to the end of the Main loop (mw = Main loop Wrap-up).
- `s/^[[:upper:]]\?[[:lower:]]\+\([[:upper:]]\)/\1/; t mw` —
  changes “amA” to “A” and “ManT” to “T”.
- `s/^[[:upper:]]\+\([[:upper:]][[:lower:]]\)/\1/; t mw` — changes “AMa” to “Ma”.
- `s/^[[:alpha:]][[:lower:]]*[._]//; t mw` —
  deletes “I_” and “you_” (replaces them with nothing).
- `s/^[[:upper:]]\+[._]//; t mw` — deletes “FOO_” (replaces it with nothing).
- Each of the above substitute commands jumps to the Main loop Wrap-up (below)
  if it succeeds (if it finds / matches something). 
  If we get here, the pattern space contains only a small word, so we’re done.
- `b` — branch (jump) to the end of the sed script;
  i.e., exit from the sed script.
- `:mw` — label for Main loop Wrap-up.
- `h` — copy the pattern space to the hold space,
  to set ourselves up for the next iteration of the Main loop.
- `b ms` — jump to the beginning of the Main loop.

It produces the requested output. 
Unfortunately, it puts it in a different order. 
I can probably fix that if it’s important.

```
$ echo "I_amAManTest you_haveAHouse FOO_BAR_test" | ./myscript
I_amAManTest
I_amAMan
I_amA
I_am
I
amAManTest
amAMan
amA
am
AManTest
AMan
A
ManTest
Man
Test
you_haveAHouse
you_haveA
you_have
you
haveAHouse
haveA
have
AHouse
A
House
FOO_BAR_test
FOO_BAR
FOO
BAR_test
BAR
Test
```

Comment: thank you so much, it's like a perfect solution, and the answer is so detail. and the order is not important.

Comment: I’m glad you like it.   If you believe that it’s the best answer, please “accept” it by clicking on the checkmark on the left.

Comment: yeah, I do it, can you extend your ansewr, if I have a '-' in the word, like 'hello-world' as 'hello, hello-world, world'.

Comment: (1) Through your follow-up question, you alerted me to a minor error in my answer, which I have now fixed. (2) To get **``-``** to behave like **`.`** and **`_`** (that’s what you want, right?), change all five occurrences of **`._`** to **`-._`**. (Order is important — the **`-`** must come first.)

Comment: hello, I use your solution in my program, but in some siuation like `_fooBar` the word startswith `_` , it's not work. the output is `_foo` and `_fooBar`, missing `foo` and `fooBar`

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is likely to find a tokenizer module for perl. Grep can't do this without multiple runs, likely needing `-P` (PCRE).

Here's a partial solution without any perl modules:

```perl
while (<>) {
  my $n = 1;
  while (/(\S+)/g) {
    printf "// outputting whitespace-separated word %d\n", $n++;
    my $whole = $1;
    while ($whole =~ /([a-zA-Z0-9][a-z]*+)/g) {
      print "$1\n";
    }
    print "$whole\n";    # whole space-delimited tokens
  }
}
```

This reads inputs from standard input or files, one line at a time. `$n` is a word counter for the printed comment, then we iterate through words (as delineated by white space, thus the regex `/(\S+)/g` globally matching consecutive non-white-space characters). Within each word, we iterate on the token parts using [`([a-zA-Z0-9][a-z]*+)`](https://regex101.com/r/d8DJr1/1), whose matches all start with numbers or letters and are followed by zero or more lowercase letters (`*+` is like `*` with backtracking disabled to protect against a [ReDoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS)). After we print all of the matched tokens in the word, we print the whole word.

You run this as `perl solution.pl intput.txt` or else inline like:

```
$ echo "I_amAManTest you_haveAHouse FOO_BAR_test.model" |perl solution.pl
// outputting whitespace-separated word 1
I
am
A
Man
Test
I_amAManTest
// outputting whitespace-separated word 2
you
have
A
House
you_haveAHouse
// outputting whitespace-separated word 3
F
O
O
B
A
R
test
model
FOO_BAR_test.model
```

Note that this is missing the multi-part subtokens of words.

Also note that your request for `I_AmAMan` to parse as `I`,`Am`,`A`,`Man` conflicts with your request for `FOO_BAR` to parse into `FOO`,`BAR` rather than `F`,`O`,`O`,`B`... as the above code does. (Perhaps a better example would be: what should `I_AmOK` become? Three unigrams or four?)

Comment: FOO_BAR_TEST, the words is FOO,BAR,TEST, testFOOBar, the words is test FOO Bar, if the UPPERCASE is flowing UPPERCASE and lowercase, it may split into UPPERCASE, UPPERCASE and lowercase, forexample: `TESTBar` would be `TEST`, `Bar`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start, you'll just have to massage it once you figure out your requirements for strings that contain mixtures of upper and lower case letters and to print the output in whatever order that is you're showing in your question:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    for (wordNr=1; wordNr<=NF; wordNr++) {
        delete ngrams
        word = $wordNr
        ngrams[word]
        print "word", word
        numUndSeps = split(word,undSeps,/_/)
        for (undSepNr=1; undSepNr<=numUndSeps; undSepNr++) {
            undSep = undSeps[undSepNr]
            ngrams[undSep]
            print "undSep", undSep
            numDotSeps = split(undSep,dotSeps,/[.]/)
            for (dotSepNr=1; dotSepNr<=numDotSeps; dotSepNr++) {
                dotSep = dotSeps[dotSepNr]
                ngrams[dotSep]
                print "dotSep", dotSep
                while ( match(dotSep,/[[:upper:]]+[^[:upper:]]+/) ) {
                    camel = substr(dotSep,RSTART,RLENGTH)
                    dotSep = substr(dotSep,RSTART+RLENGTH)
                    ngrams[camel]
                    print "camel", camel
                }
            }
        }
        print "-----------"
        for (ngram in ngrams) {
            print ngram
        }
        print "###########"
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
word I_amAManTest
undSep I
dotSep I
undSep amAManTest
dotSep amAManTest
camel AMan
camel Test
-----------
Test
amAManTest
I_amAManTest
I
AMan
###########
word you_haveAHouse
undSep you
dotSep you
undSep haveAHouse
dotSep haveAHouse
camel AHouse
-----------
you
you_haveAHouse
haveAHouse
AHouse
###########
word FOO_BAR_test.model
undSep FOO
dotSep FOO
undSep BAR
dotSep BAR
undSep test.model
dotSep test
dotSep model
-----------
model
FOO
FOO_BAR_test.model
test.model
BAR
test
###########
```

Comment: hello, thank you for your answer, I modified the question, can you please output the same as my output in question?

Comment: You're welcome. I showed you the code for an approach, you can finish it from here.